# Problems with using \begin{multline} \end{multline]

Tags: math-mode

I have the long equation

```
$$frac{1}{2^j}K_{b_0}K_{b_1}..K_{b_{j-1}}K_{b_j}= 
\frac{(\sqrt{2})^j}{2^{j-1}}exp{[(-1)^{b_1}-(-1)^{b_2}+ (-1)^{b_3}- ... 
+(-1)^{j-2}(-1)^{b_{j-1}}+ (-1)^{j-1}]\frac{i \pi}{4}}$$
```

I want to split it up.

So I use multline

```
\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{2^j}K_{b_0}K_{b_1}..K_{b_{j-1}}K_{b_j}= 
\frac{(\sqrt{2})^j}{2^{j-1}}exp{[(-1)^{b_1}-(-1)^{b_2}+ (-1)^{b_3}- ... 

+(-1)^{j-2}(-1)^{b_{j-1}}+ (-1)^{j-1}]\frac{i \pi}{4}}
\end{multline}
```

If I try to split the equation up after the first equal sign by putting \ \ , it works. But if I try to break it up anywhere else, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `\exp` math operator, and remove the pair of braces around the argument of `exp`. I propose this way of splitting the formula. I think the lines should be closer than the default so I used `\\[-1ex]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{2^j}K_{b_0}K_{b_1}..K_{b_{j-1}}K_{b_j}=
\frac{(\sqrt{2})^j}{2^{j-1}}\exp\bigl[(-1)^{b_1}-(-1)^{b_2}+ (-1)^{b_3}- \dots\\[-1ex]
\dots +(-1)^{j-2}(-1)^{b_{j-1}}+ (-1)^{j-1}\bigr]\frac{i \pi}{4}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are breaking up the curley brackets `{` and `}` after `exp`.

I guess you wanted to use `\exp{}`, and this is where the brackets came from.
You can get the same result by removing the brackets and placing `ext` in a `\text` environment:

```
\begin{multline}
\frac{1}{2^j}K_{b_0}K_{b_1}..K_{b_{j-1}}K_{b_j}= 
\frac{(\sqrt{2})^j}{2^{j-1}} \text{exp} [(-1)^{b_1}-(-1)^{b_2}+(-1)^{b_3}-\\
%                            ^^^^^^^^^^
...+(-1)^{j-2}(-1)^{b_{j-1}}+ (-1)^{j-1}]\frac{i \pi}{4}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: The `\exp` command does not take an argument, so it doesn't need braces. If you're used to type `\exp{(i\pi)}`, you should know that `\exp(i\pi)` does exactly the same and is preferable. Your suggestion of `\text{exp}` is wrong, I'm afraid.